# Examples and applications of Baire measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Royden's "Real Analysis", which contains Baire measures. Do you know some applications of this theory about Baire measures? I also want to know some important nontrivial examples of Baire measures.

Indeed I am always wondering how you can find a nontrivial example or an application to help you understand the power of a theorem after you read it.

Comment: In metric spaces, Baire measures and Borel measures coincide. This gives you already a rich class of examples.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what I am looking for are some Baire measures which are not Borel measures, and more important these examples should have some importance in some other subjects.